# New Google Apps for Business dashboard

Tags: google-app-engine

I have (several) AppEngine apps.

How do I manage SSL for them in a custom domain with the new "Google Apps for Business" dashboard?

I was able to do it with the old "Admin Console".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a small "Show more" link on the "Security" menu, which you have to press to show the "SSL for Custom Domains" link.